# Encapsulating repetitive binding parameters in Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, markup-extensions

*I hope this is a duplicate, but I seem to be having searchers block...*

---

In WPF forms, I'm finding myself repeatedly specifying a consistent set of Binding parameters via a lot of cut/paste, e.g.:-

> `<dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />`
>
> ...
>
> `<dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{Binding Days, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />`

What's the cleanest way to define a markup extension (or something equivalent but more appropriate) which allows me to remove the boilerplate and be able to replace that with e.g.:

> `<dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{mine:EditorBinding Name}" />`
>
> ...
>
> `<dxe:TextEdit EditValue="{mine:EditorBinding Days>" />`

For bonus points, it would be nice to still be able to override the established default for the 5% of cases where that is necessary [but if something small can accomplish the core goal cleanly with minimal fuss, that'll do nicely either...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply create a derived `Binding` class, because `Binding` is already derived from `MarkupExtension`.

```
public class EditorBinding : Binding
{
    public EditorBinding()
    {
        UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        ValidatesOnDataErrors = true;
        NotifyOnValidationError = true;
    }

    public EditorBinding(PropertyPath path)
        : this()
    {
        Path = path;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yay, works like a dream [on my machine, so far, E&OE :P] ,thanks!

Comment: Damn, falls foul of [`Type '{0}' is used like a markup extension but does not derive from MarkupExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514522(v=vs.90).aspx), searching for workaround...

Comment: It works for me too, but VS2015 puts wavies all over them which kinda ruins it all :)

Comment: Nothing like that in my VS2015.

Comment: OK, restarting VS didn't cure the `XAML0505`, neither did rebuilding. But adding a second copy in a local project made VS happy (including with it in an extensions project). I guess it's that Cache Invalidation thing again eh :) Thanks once again for your time!

Comment: Wow, the same problem recurred in another file and the only cure was to add [,use and subsequently remove] a new markup extension in the local project.